# vba code to get data from td rowspan & td colspan using selenium firefox

Tags: vba, selenium

I want to get data from td rowspan & td colspan both having same class (ng-binding).I require output 100 from td rowspan="4" and 38.6% from td colspan="6".
Below is my html code:

```html
<td rowspan="4" class="ng-binding">Subscription used in terms of Duration:100</td>
<td colspan="6" class="ng-binding">38.6%</td>
```

Below is the code which i have try but getting error message Run time error '438' Object does't support this property or method at `Set TDs = driver.findElementByClassName("ng-binding")`

```
Sub edit()
Dim driver As New selenium.FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "url"
Dim TDs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim td As IHTMLElement
Set TDs = driver.findElementByClass("ng-binding")
For Each td In TDs
 If InStr(td.innerHTML, "rowspan=""4""") > 0 Then s = td.innerText
 If InStr(td.innerHTML, "td colspan=""6""") > 0 Then
    s = td.innerText
    s = Right(s, Len(s) - InStr(s, ":"))
 End If
 Debug.Print s
Next td
End Sub
```

Comment: You error says `findElementByClassName` and code says `findElementByClass`? It should be `findElementByClass` as such

Answer (score 0):

Let say that html variable is html code that your macro downloaded. I would do it this way:

```
Dim TDs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim td As IHTMLElement

Set TDs = html.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")
For Each td In TDs
 If InStr(td.innerHTML, "rowspan=""4""") > 0 Then s = td.innerText
 If InStr(td.innerHTML, "td colspan=""6""") > 0 Then
    s = td.innerText
    s = Right(s, Len(s) - InStr(s, ":"))
 End If
 Debug.Print s
Next td
```

It should work if there is just one ":" within < td rowspan="4" class="ng-binding" >.

Comment: Hi MarcinSzaleniec, Thanks for the reply.Actually i am using selenium firefox so request you yo please help me how to use this code in selenium firefox.